# regex negative lookbehind matching when expected not to

Tags: regex, perl

Can someone help me understand why the following regex is matching when i would expect it not to match.

String to check against

```
/opt/lnpsite/ni00/flat/tmp/Med_Local_Bak/ROI_Med_Transfer/CBD99_PINPUK_14934_09_02_2017_12_07_36.txt
```

regex

```
(?<!Transfer\/)\w*PINPUK.*(?:csv|txt)$
```

I was expecting this to not match as the string `Transfer/` appears before 0 or more word chars followed by the string `PINPUK`. If I change the pattern from `\w*` to `\w{6}` to explicitly match 6 word chars this correctly returns no match.

Can someone help me understand why with the 0 or more quantifier on my "word" character results in the regex giving a match?

Comment: With `(?<!Transfer\/)` you prevent it from matching at `CBD99_PINPUK`, but there's nothing to prevent it from skipping the `C` and matching at `BD99_PINPUK`

Comment: `\w*` allows backtracking as `*` can match any amount of chars, while `{6}` matches an exact number of chars and cannot backtrack here.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/s0SdxA/1 also shows this nicely.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: it isn't related to backtracking but to the position where the pattern is tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex pattern `(?<!Transfer/)\w*PINPUK.*(?:csv|txt)$` is looking for `\w*PINPUK` *not* immediately preceded by `Transfer/`

Given the string

```
/opt/lnpsite/ni00/flat/tmp/Med_Local_Bak/ROI_Med_Transfer/CBD99_PINPUK_14934_09_02_2017_12_07_36.txt
```

the regex engine will start by matching `\w*PINPUK` with `CBD99_PINPUK`

But that is preceded by `Transfer/` so the engine backtracks and finds `BD99_PINPUK`

That is preceded by `C`, which isn't `Transfer/`, so the match is successful

---

As for a fix, just put the slash outside the look-behind

```
(?<!Transfer)/\w*PINPUK.*(?:csv|txt)$
```

That forces the `\w*` to begin right after the slash, and the pattern now correctly fails

Answer (score 2):

Borodin has given an excellent explanation of why this doesn't work and a solution for this case (move a /). Sometimes something simple like that isn't possible though so here I'll explain an alternate work around that might be useful

Things will match as you expect if you move the `\w*` inside the negative look-behind. Like so:

```
(?<!Transfer\/\w*)PINPUK.*(?:csv|txt)$
```

Unfortunately Perl doesn't allow this, negative look-behinds must be fixed width. But still, there is a way to perform one match: **match in reverse**

```
^(?:vsc|txt).*KUPNIP(?!\w*\/refsnarT)
```

This uses a variable length negative look-ahead, something Perl does allow. Putting all this together in a script we get

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $string_matches = '/opt/lnpsite/ni00/flat/tmp/Med_Local_Bak/ROI_Med_Transfer/CBD99_PINPUK_14934_09_02_2017_12_07_36.txt';
say "Trying $string_matches";
if ( reverse($string_matches) =~ /^(?:vsc|txt).*KUPNIP(?!\w*\/refsnarT)/ ) {
    say 'It matched';
} else {
    say 'No match';
}

say '';

my $string_doesnt_match = '/opt/lnpsite/ni00/flat/tmp/Med_Local_Bak/ROI_Med/CBD99_PINPUK_14934_09_02_2017_12_07_36.txt';
say "Trying $string_doesnt_match";
if ( reverse($string_doesnt_match) =~ /^(?:vsc|txt).*KUPNIP(?!\w*\/refsnarT)/ ) {
    say 'It matched';
} else {
    say 'No match';
}
```

Which outputs

```
Trying /opt/lnpsite/ni00/flat/tmp/Med_Local_Bak/ROI_Med_Transfer/CBD99_PINPUK_14934_09_02_2017_12_07_36.txt
No match

Trying /opt/lnpsite/ni00/flat/tmp/Med_Local_Bak/ROI_Med/CBD99_PINPUK_14934_09_02_2017_12_07_36.txt
It matched
```

Comment: Much simpler: just add `/` to the match!